# How to Read first x characters of each line of a text file

Tags: vb.net

HI have a Program that loops through a text file and reads the lines.

```
Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")

            Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("C:\test.txt").Length
            MsgBox(lineCount)
          For x = 1 to linecount
            line = r.ReadLine
            msgbox (line)
          next
```

How can I read the Left most 15 characters of each line of the text file, ignoring the other characters in each line.  Lastly, if there are spaces in the first 15 characters, i'd like to remove them.

Comment: Yes, all is in the documentation : Substring (beware of shorter than 15 chars lines) ; Trim

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You're already reading all of the line (with `r.ReadLine`). Are you asking how to just get the 15 leftmost characters and remove spaces, or are you asking about doing that and then writing the file back out? (And questions asking *Is this possible?* generally do not fare well here; almost anything is *possible*, and the direct answer to your question as asked is *Yes, this is possible* with no other content. Would that answer help you? If not, rephrase your question to be more specific.)

Comment: I can't see any loop in your code. And by the way, calling ReadAllLines to discover how many lines are there seems to be a waste of resources. How big is your file? Reading all lines in a single call could be a better option if you don't have too many lines

Comment: Do you want to remove spaces just from the end/begin of line or do you want to remove all spaces (also in the middle of the line)?

Comment: All spaces in the middle of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Calling ReadAllLines to discover how many lines are there to drive a for..loop is wrong and a waste of resources (Essentially you are reading all the file content two times). In particular consider that a StreamReader has a method that tells you if you have reached the end of file

So everything could be changed to a simpler

```
Dim clippedLines = new List(Of String)()
Dim line As String
Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
     While r.Peek() >= 0
         line = r.ReadLine
         Dim temp = if(line.Length > 15, line.Substring(0,15), line)
         clippedLines.Add(temp.Trim().Replace(" "c, ""))
     End While
End Using
```

This will remove all the spaces from the line AFTER taking the first 15 char (and thus the result could be a string shorter than 15 chars) If you want a line of 15 char after the space removing operation, then

```
     While r.Peek() >= 0
         line = r.ReadLine.Trim().Replace(" "c, "")
         Dim temp = if(line.Length > 15, line.Substring(0,15), line)
         clippedLines.Add(temp)
     End While
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to remove all whitespace, not just the ends. Instead of `Trim`, use `Replace(" ", "")`.